# DB2 select multiple rows into single result

Tags: sql, db2

I have a DB2 table containing rows of customer data. This is used to determine if a customer saved money using our service. The older record is the purchase that triggered our process and the newer record is after they purchase the same product again. The desired result is to see one row containing their oldest paid amount, their newest amount and the difference between the two rows to verify they saved money.

The data is laid out like this

```
ID       Name       Product ID    Sale ID      First Paid     Last Paid
1        Mary       15            195          8              NULL
2        Mary       15            195          NULL           3
3        Bob        8             283          16             NULL
4        Bob        8             283          NULL           11
```

The desired result is this

```
Name     Sale ID    Product ID     First Paid  Last Paid    Savings     
Mary     195        15             8           3            5
Bob      283        8              16          11           5
```

This is what I get instead

```
Name    Sale ID    Product ID     First Paid     Last Paid     Savings   
Mary    195        15             8              NULL          8
Mary    195        15             NULL           3             -3
Bob     283        8              16             NULL          16
Bob     283        8              NULL           11            -11
```

The results of this query are used to drive a larger report so this is being generated as part of a subquery.

```
SELECT cost.name, cost.saleid, cost.productid, cost.saleid,
cost.firstpaid, cost.lastpaid, sum(cost.firstpaid - cost.lastpaid) as savings 
from (
    select distinct saleid, max(name) as name, max(productid) as productid, 
    max(firstpaid) as firstpaid, max(lastpaid) as lastpaid) as cost
```

I have found that my larger query works as intended but the multiple rows returned by this innermost query is having a negative impact on the results as customers are counted twice when they should only be counted once. Is there a way in DB2 to get these values into the same row or will I need to pull back the results and filter them in php code rather than in the SQL query?

Comment: Did you intentionally mean to have 'cost.saleid' twice? Could that be causing the duplicate entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming two rows per customer, then aggregation seems like the right approach:

```
select Name, SaleID, ProductID,
       sum(firstpaid) as firstpaid, sum(lastpaid) as lastpaid
       sum(firstpaid) - sum(lastpaid) as savings
from t
group by Name, SaleID, ProductID;
```

This works for more than two rows.  I'm not sure if you want `sum()` or `min()` or `max()` or `avg()` when there are additional rows.

Comment: be carefull sum(firstpaid) - sum(lastpaid) return null if sum(firstpaid) is null or sum(lastpaid)  is null. May be you can use sum(ifnull(firstpaid, 0)) and into other sum instead ;)